# Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range: item length 0 but minimum is 1

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, web-frontend

Hello I am using `FlatListSlider` and getting this error (`Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of =range: item length 0 but minimum is 1`) on passing data in `data={PinnedCards}`. Here PinnedCards is a state name.

This is how my `flatlistslider` component looks like -

```js
<FlatListSlider
    data={displayPinnedCards && displayPinnedCards}
    component={<Preview navigation={navigation} />}
    onPress={item => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
    indicatorActiveColor={'#007585'}
    indicatorInActiveColor={'#ffffff'}
    separatorWidth={20}
    loop={false}
/>
```

This preview component is my custom component. and this is how it looks like -

```js
<Card style={styles.container}>
  <Card.Content style={styles.cardContent}>
    {item.pinned ? (
      <Ionicons
        style={styles.favorite}
        name="heart"
        size={22}
        onPress={() => callF(item.clientId, false)}
      />
     ) : (
      <Ionicons
        style={styles.favorite}
        name="heart-outline"
        size={22}
        onPress={() => callF(item.clientId, true)}
      />
      )}
  </Card.Content>
</Card>
```

every time when there is change in state item prop should be updated but its not getting updated

Answer (score 1):

when you write the following:

```
data={displayPinnedCards && displayPinnedCards}
```

it means if displayPinnedCards is true (contains information), it will return an array, but if it is undefined or null or false, it will return undefined. Your problem lies here, the "data" takes an array as an argument

so try this:

```
<FlatListSlider
   data={displayPinnedCards ? displayPinnedCards : []}
   component={<Preview navigation={navigation} />}
   onPress={item => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
   indicatorActiveColor={'#007585'}
   indicatorInActiveColor={'#ffffff'}
   separatorWidth={20}
   loop={false}
  />
```